# getline(cin,_string);

Tags: c++, string, getline

I know that `getline(cin,_string);` works perfectly

but this dosen't:

```
char* _chArr = new char;
getline(cin,_chArr);
```

Even this alson doesn't work:

```
char* _chArr = new char[30];
getline(cin,_chArr);
```

Isn't `char*` a string??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well think of it logically. the char* is just a pointer to a character type memory block. You have to assign it some amount of dynamic memory and then copy data into it using strcpy() or manually. Direct input is not supported in C++. Strings are in fact objects which contain size within themselves. They are designed by the experts in this industry, and they have provided the direct input and dynamic growth as in built functionality.
There is a differnce between string and cstring. Cstring is the char*.

Comment: i'm sorry guys,i did type "new" in the above code already !


isn't char* x =new char*; or char* x =new char* [100];

aren't these two condsidered to be strings ??

Comment: no, you are very, very confused. even though a string might look like a character array, it is a type in and of itself. they're similar, but not the same. that's like saying someone who shares a resemblance with you - is you. it isn't true, and the compiler speaks in absolutes. if you have some char* you want to pass to getline() for some reason - you need to convert it to a string first.

Comment: these are condidered to be cstrings. Do not confuse cstrings with strings. Direct input is not allowed in a cstring.
Take input in a string or a static char array and then copy the data into the char*

Comment: Can do it like this.....
char str[50] ;
cin.getline (str, 50) ;
_chArr = new char [strlen (str)] ;
strcpy (_chArr, str) ;

Answer (score 5):

> isn't char* is a string

No, it's a pointer to a `char` and that's that. The function `std::getline` does some cool stuff (extending the string and all) that can't be done easily on a `char *`.

Comment: isn't char* x =new char; a string ?

Comment: @user1609974 Nope, it's not. It's a pointer to which you allocated exactly one byte.

Comment: @user1609974 [That's right](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: so i have to use cin.getline to use the char* and specify the length before

Comment: @user1609974 Not sure what you mean. What C++ book are you using ?

Comment: oki think it is but i am convincing myself to continue as i took 3 chapters now in it

i wish there was a headfirst c++ but i didn't find any :(

do u recommend a book like headfirst ?

Answer (score 1):

No, C++ strings are *not* just character arrays, they are a full blown class, usually with quite a bit of extra stuff under the covers, over and above what a character array provides.