# difference between char c[100] and char *c both with cin.getline()

Tags: c++, new-operator, getline, c-strings

I have some questions on cin.getline(char *s, int num_char, char delim);

what is the difference between:

```
char c[100];  
cin.getline(c,100,'\n');
```

and

```
char *c = new char[100]; //this is the correct form I want to show you 
cin.getline(c,100,'\n');
```

I know only one thing, the second does not work :-)

Comment: In what way does the second not work? Originally you had a syntax error although that has been fixed now.

Comment: @john: CodingMash appears to have answered the question in an edit.

Comment: @Coding Mash: Why'd you edit the code?  Don't do that, unless the OP admits it was a mistake in translation.

Answer (score 3):

Your second code snippet is a syntax error. Like this will work

```
char *c = new char[100];  
cin.getline(c,100,'\n');
```

The difference between the two is that in the second case the memory is dynamically allocated. This has two effects, firstly the array is not automatically destroyed, with the first example the array would automatically be destroyed when you exited the function it was declared in. The second effect is that unless you do destroy the array with `delete[]` you have a memory leak. Enough memory leaks and your program will crash.

Choose the version you want based on when you want the array to be destroyed, automatically at the end of the function, or when you say so by using `delete[]`. Of course really you should be using `std::string`.

Comment: Then you have an error somewhere else in your code. It's very common in C++ for a error in one part of your program to cause a crash in another part of your program. If you want help with this you are going to have to post the whole program. There is nothing wrong with the code that has been posted so far (either version).

Comment: It works now. Thanks. But it is the first time that this code work with char *c = new char[1000] and cin.getline(c,1000,'\n'). Ok, all the code works fine now. Just a question: between Qt and wxWidget which GUI is most easier to learn and more sophisticated in the sens that it provides powerfull class and eaiser to use

Comment: This is the big problem with C++. Just because your code works, doesn't mean that it contains no errors. If `char *c = new char[1000]; cin.getline(c,1000,'\n');` was not working for you before then you had an error elsewhere in your code. Are you confident that you've found it? As I said just because it's working now doesn't mean you've fixed the error you had before.

Comment: no no, it really works now, I have just had some condition on some char pointers and all goes in the rigth way now. Now if I want a GUI API which API is the most interesting between Qt and wxWidget??

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not allow you to take input directly in a character pointer, through `cin` or `getline`. If you want to take input in a dynamically allocated cstring, first take input in a static char array and use `strcpy()` to copy data into char pointer.

See my answer here
[getline(cin,_string);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026541/getlinecin-string/12026619#12026619)

Comment: There are two getline functions.  One is a member of the istream class, and that one does take a char pointer.

Comment: From the documentation for `std::basic_istream`: " `basic_istream<charT,traits>& getline(char_type* s, streamsize n,
char_type delim);`
Effects: Behaves as an unformatted input function (as described in 27.7.2.3, paragraph 1). After constructing a sentry object, extracts characters and stores them into successive locations of an array whose first element is designated by `s`. "

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
getchar()
```

or

```
gets()
```

the returning value will be a char*.
sometimes problems occurred because of having buffer not clean.
so clean it with:

```
cin.ignore()
```

Answer (score -1):

for one when you call c is being passed by reference and in the second case c is passed as a pointer.

The second case is the same as:

```
char c[100];
Char *p = &c;
cin.getline(p,100,'\n');
```

Comment: There are no references in either case. Your code example does not compile.

Comment: No. `c` will decay to a pointer to its first element when being passed to a function taking a pointer which is exactly what is required.

Comment: Charles, the original did not compile, so it is not surprising that code that is functionally the same does not compile.